# CRON JOB is not running script

Tags: magento, cron

I'm trying to schedule a `cron job` here is my command:

```
*/5 * * * * USER -q /path/cron.php -mdefault 1
```

I'm trying to run this magento script every 5 minutes. I see the command being run when I open the `cron` log via `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`.

unfortunately the script never executes. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: USER is the runner user ?

Comment: Have you set a cron execution on your server?

Comment: You have to use `PHP` command within cron to run `/path/cron.php`

Answer (score 0):

Edit the crontab of the user you want to assign the job to:

```
sudo -u USER crontab -e
```

then in the crontab you can schedule the cron.php job in the following way:

```
*/5    *       *       *       *       php /path/to/cron.php
```